# EmberJS - Update computed properties when same value is assigned to dependent property

Tags: javascript, properties, ember.js, dependencies

Within my ember application, there is an event where a model's property may or may not change.  I also have a computed property in my controller that it dependent on both my model's property and another variable within my application (not belonging to a model).

Even if the model's property does not change when the even triggers, the other application variable changes, which affects the controller's computed property, and I would like those changes to be reflected on the event triggering.

I've noticed that ember will not 'update' a property if the same value is assigned to it, and I cannot seem to find a way to force the update.

Right now I have a cheese fix, where if the model's property does not change, I change the value to something else, then reset it back to what it was in order to trigger the controller's computed property.  This is not very efficient or clean.  Is there another way to handle this?

Edit:
To show briefly what I have going on...

```
session.other_application_var = [1, 2];

App.MyModel = Ember.Object.extend({
  model_prop: 1
});

//an instance of MyModel is assigned to the index route's model

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  comp_prop: function(){
    var sum = this.get('model.model_prop');
    session.other_application_var.forEach(function(num){
      sum += num;
    });
    return sum;
  }.property('model.model_prop)
});
```

So basically, if I change session.other_application_var, such as add another element, I would like comp_prop to update.

Comment: can you show code, of what your are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the special [`@each` property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) to observe changes in arrays. The changes below mean that `comp_prop` will update when `model.model_prop` or 'App.otherStuff.@each' changes.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  otherStuff: [2,3,4]
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  comp_prop: function(){
    var sum = this.get('model.model_prop');
    var otherStuff = App.get('otherStuff');
    otherStuff.forEach(function(num){
      sum += num;
    });
    return sum;
  }.property('model.model_prop', 'App.otherStuff.@each')
}
```

[Full working example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/289/edit)

Comment: So there is no way to observe a variable that is not within the Ember app?

Comment: I think that's true. Ember handles the observing/data binding details internally so it only works with ember variables.